# Login view keeps showing up again and again

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a login in view, I check the username and password from UserDefaults, if they match I go to FirstView

However I an getting thrown back to Login in view after successful login, on restart of app all works well, can any one please suggest

I am trying to keep it as simple as possible , but just do not seem to know where to make the change

my file with @main

```
@main
struct demoApp: App {
    @StateObject var dataController =  DataController.shared
    init() {
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
            "username": "test@test.com", "password": "demo", "logData": false
        ])
    }
    let userInfo = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "logData")
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            ContentView(data: dataController)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

my login file

```
struct LoginPage: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    let userData = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username")
    let userPassword = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "password")
    @State var credStatus = false
    @State var showerroralert = false
    @ObservedObject var data: DataController
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Welcome")
                    .font(.title)
                Image("carbg")
                    .resizable()
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    .padding()
                
                    .cornerRadius(5.0)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .padding()
                
                    .cornerRadius(5.0)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                
                Button("Login") {
                    if (userData == username && userPassword == password) {
                        credStatus = true
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "logData")
                        

                    } else {
                        showerroralert = true
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .alert("Wrong data", isPresented: $showerroralert) {
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $credStatus) {
                ContentView(data: data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my content file

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: DataController
    @State var userInfo = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "logData")
    
    var body: some View {
        if userInfo {
            FirstView()
        } else {
            LoginPage(data: data)
        }
        
        
     
           
       
    }
        
}
```

UPDATED LOGIN PAGE

```
struct LoginPage: View {
    @State var usernameTemp: String = ""
    @State var passwordTemp: String = ""
   // let userData = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username")
    //let userPassword = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "password")
    @State var credStatus = false
    @State var showerroralert = false
    @ObservedObject var data: DataController
    
    @AppStorage("username") var username: String = "test@demo.tech"
    @AppStorage("password") var password: String = "demo"
    @AppStorage("logData") var logData: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Welcome")
                    .font(.title)
                Image("carbg")
                    .resizable()
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                TextField("Username", text: $usernameTemp)
                    .padding()
                
                    .cornerRadius(5.0)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                SecureField("Password", text: $passwordTemp)
                    .padding()
                
                    .cornerRadius(5.0)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                
                Button("Login") {
                    if (usernameTemp == username && passwordTemp == password) {
                        credStatus = true
                        logData = true
                        

                    } else {
                        showerroralert = true
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .alert("Wrong data", isPresented: $showerroralert) {
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $credStatus) {
                ContentView(data: data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use AppStorage instead

Comment: thanks, I updated the new login page in my question , but seems to repeat the old behavior

Comment: Why do you have the `ContentView` in `navigationDestination` if that is where it all starts? You are just creating different instances of the same thing. Make sure you change all of the `UserDefault` lines to `AppStorage`, especially the `ContentView`

Comment: thanks, calling ContentView in Navigation was the issue